# Помогите с выводом массива через angular

Tags: json, angularjs

Для одного проекта нужно сделать таблички. В JS я не бум-бум. С помощью Angular пытаюсь сформировать табличку, что у меня есть

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="pilot in dannye.pilots">
   <td>{{pilot.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="i in pilot.rating track by $index"><input readonly="" type=text value="{{i}}"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Пытаюсь как то так еще:

```
  <table> <tr ng-repeat="pilot in dannye.pilots">
   <td>{{pilot.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="rating in pilot.rating track by $index"><input readonly="{{pilot.read[$index]}}" type=text value="{{rating}}"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Главное, что если сделать так:
   
   {{pilot.name}}
   {{pilot.read[$index]}}
   

В ячейке выводится строка readonly, там где она должна быть. Но как подставить это значение в атрибук **readonly**
Чувствую, что где то хожу рядом, похожая проблема [ТУТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749810/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ng-repeat-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0), но пока не могу решить задачу....
Часть файла из массива JSON

```
[
"pilots" :
{"name": "Сидоров А. А.",
        "rating": ["4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"],
        "color": ["yellow","yellow","yellow","red","red"],
        "read": ["readonly","","","","readonly",""]
        },
{"name": "Петров А. А.",
        "rating": ["4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"],
        "color": ["yellow","yellow","yellow","red","red"],
        "read": ["readonly","","","","readonly",""]
        }
]
```

Все значения rating выводятся как надо. Но мне необходимо, чтобы в атрибут **readonly** тега **input** подставлялись последовательно значения из массива "read".  Весь JSON массив у меня записывается из файла так:

```
var dannyeApp = angular.module('dannyeApp', []);
dannyeApp.controller('DannyeCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
$http.get('001-4.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.dannye = data; 
});
});
```

Возможно ли это сделать чисто с помощью Angular? Пытаюсь второй день(...
Или все таки нужны какие то дополнительные телодвижения? Очень буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение! Ура! Модет кому будет полезно оказывается (да для меня открытие), есть деректива ng-readonly в которую можно записать true или false. Отредактировав JSON типа так:

```
{"name": "Сидоров А. А.",
"rating": ["4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"],
"color": ["yellow","yellow","yellow","red","red"],
"read": ["true","","","","true",""]
}
```

А HTML так:

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="pilot in dannye.pilots">
   <td>{{pilot.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="rating in pilot.rating track by $index"><input ng-readonly="{{pilot.read[$index]}}" type=text value="{{rating}}"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Все заработало!